# React send child component data to parent component and POST request

Tags: reactjs, http-post, react-component

I'm trying to send data from Child component to parent component using call back function.

This is my parent component

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
   e.preventDefault()
   try {
    const response = await promiseApp.post('/promises', {
      id: "", 
      uuid: "",
      content: promise,
      date: date,
      time: time,
      place: place,
      phone_number: phone
    })
    addPromise(response.data.promise)
    history.push('/promises')
   } catch (err) {
      alert("An error has occured")
      console.log(err)
      console.log('zzzzzzzz')
   }
 }

 const updateNumbersInParent = (number) => {
   console.log(number)
   console.log('hhhhhhhhhh')
  let value = number.map((element) => {
    return element.newNumber
  })
  console.log(value)
  for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    console.log(value[i])
    setPhone(value[i])
  }
  }

  return (
        <div className="tile is-parent">
          <article className="tile is-child box">
            <PhoneNumber phone={phone} setPhone={setPhone} onChange={value => setPhone(value)} 
             updateNumbersInParent={updateNumbersInParent}/>
          </article>
        </div>
)
```

This is my child component

```
function PhoneNumber (props) {
    // const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState([])

    const addNumberButton = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        addPhoneNumber(props.phone)
        props.setPhone('')
      }

    const addPhoneNumber = (newNumber) => {
        const addNewPhoneNumber = [...phoneNumber, {newNumber}]
        setPhoneNumber(addNewPhoneNumber)
        props.updateNumbersInParent(addNewPhoneNumber)
    }

    const deletePhoneNumber = (number) => {
        const filteredPhoneNumbers = phoneNumber.filter(currentPhoneNumbers => (currentPhoneNumbers !== number))
        setPhoneNumber(filteredPhoneNumbers)
        props.updateNumbersInParent(filteredPhoneNumbers)
    }

    return (
          <>
          <p className="title">Type a phone number and click add</p>
          <div className="field">
            <div className="control">
                <button className="button is-primary" onClick={addNumberButton}>Add</button>
                <p><b>No. of phone numbers:</b></p>
                <input className="input is-danger" pattern='^\+[1-9]\d{1,14}$' value={props.phone} onChange={e => props.onChange(e.target.value)} type="tel" placeholder="Enter your phone number here"></input>
                <p>(Format: +10000000000)</p>
            </div>
                <ul>
                    {phoneNumber.map((number, index) => {
                        return (
                            <>
                            <li key={index}>{number.newNumber}</li>
                            <button onClick={() => deletePhoneNumber(number)}>Delete</button>
                            </>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
          </div>
          </>
    )
}
```

I can see that the data from Child component has been passed to the Parent component but keep getting an error when I do POST request. phone_number property in the parent component has an empty value every time I do the POST request.

Comment: And where is `phone` coming from in the first snippet? Can you add the full file?

Comment: You have some confused state between parent and child - I can see some sort of list of phone numbers, and also a singular phone number?
Both components control some state, but it isn't clear which is which, not helped by the list having a singular variable names, and multiple callbacks being called each time.
I would suggest cleaning all that up, and reducing the props to just two callbacks.

Comment: Here are the complete codes.
parent: https://gist.github.com/henrylee0327/c661839d8aa3140db781dad41314c0be
child: https://gist.github.com/henrylee0327/e8cfbd470ee1ee6b929ee10e9be7e0f9

Comment: I want the new numbers to be sent to the server in line 34 of my POST request

Comment: context Provider:
https://gist.github.com/henrylee0327/e70cbbaa48105dc993005b31dd5a4228